# How to Detect if I'm Compiling Code with a particular Visual Studio version?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there any way to know if I'm compiling under a specific Microsoft Visual Studio version?

Answer (score 543, accepted):

`_MSC_VER` and possibly `_MSC_FULL_VER` is what you need. You can also examine [visualc.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/config/compiler/visualc.hpp) in any recent boost install for some usage examples.

Some values for the more recent versions of the compiler are:

```
MSVC++ 14.30 _MSC_VER == 1933 (Visual Studio 2022 version 17.3.4)
MSVC++ 14.30 _MSC_VER == 1932 (Visual Studio 2022 version 17.2.2)
MSVC++ 14.30 _MSC_VER == 1930 (Visual Studio 2022 version 17.0.2)
MSVC++ 14.30 _MSC_VER == 1930 (Visual Studio 2022 version 17.0.1)
MSVC++ 14.28 _MSC_VER == 1929 (Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11.2)
MSVC++ 14.28 _MSC_VER == 1928 (Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9.2)
MSVC++ 14.28 _MSC_VER == 1928 (Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8.2)
MSVC++ 14.28 _MSC_VER == 1928 (Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8.1)
MSVC++ 14.27 _MSC_VER == 1927 (Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7)
MSVC++ 14.26 _MSC_VER == 1926 (Visual Studio 2019 version 16.6.2)
MSVC++ 14.25 _MSC_VER == 1925 (Visual Studio 2019 version 16.5.1)
MSVC++ 14.24 _MSC_VER == 1924 (Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4)
MSVC++ 14.23 _MSC_VER == 1923 (Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3)
MSVC++ 14.22 _MSC_VER == 1922 (Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2)
MSVC++ 14.21 _MSC_VER == 1921 (Visual Studio 2019 version 16.1)
MSVC++ 14.2  _MSC_VER == 1920 (Visual Studio 2019 version 16.0)
MSVC++ 14.16 _MSC_VER == 1916 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9)
MSVC++ 14.15 _MSC_VER == 1915 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8)
MSVC++ 14.14 _MSC_VER == 1914 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7)
MSVC++ 14.13 _MSC_VER == 1913 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6)
MSVC++ 14.12 _MSC_VER == 1912 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5)
MSVC++ 14.11 _MSC_VER == 1911 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3)
MSVC++ 14.1  _MSC_VER == 1910 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.0)
MSVC++ 14.0  _MSC_VER == 1900 (Visual Studio 2015 version 14.0)
MSVC++ 12.0  _MSC_VER == 1800 (Visual Studio 2013 version 12.0)
MSVC++ 11.0  _MSC_VER == 1700 (Visual Studio 2012 version 11.0)
MSVC++ 10.0  _MSC_VER == 1600 (Visual Studio 2010 version 10.0)
MSVC++ 9.0   _MSC_FULL_VER == 150030729 (Visual Studio 2008, SP1)
MSVC++ 9.0   _MSC_VER == 1500 (Visual Studio 2008 version 9.0)
MSVC++ 8.0   _MSC_VER == 1400 (Visual Studio 2005 version 8.0)
MSVC++ 7.1   _MSC_VER == 1310 (Visual Studio .NET 2003 version 7.1)
MSVC++ 7.0   _MSC_VER == 1300 (Visual Studio .NET 2002 version 7.0)
MSVC++ 6.0   _MSC_VER == 1200 (Visual Studio 6.0 version 6.0)
MSVC++ 5.0   _MSC_VER == 1100 (Visual Studio 97 version 5.0)
```

The version number above of course refers to the major version of your Visual studio you see in the about box, not to the year in the name.  A thorough list can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering). [Starting recently](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/visual-c-compiler-version/), Visual Studio will start updating its ranges monotonically, meaning you should check ranges, rather than exact compiler values.

`cl.exe /?` will give a hint of the used version, e.g.:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\bin>cl /?
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 for x86
.....
```

Comment: Sorry, but why don't Microsoft make this information easy to find? this post is very useful but shouldn't be required.

Comment: It appear that this macro doesn't reflect the compiler version used by the project. I.e. if you open a VS2010 project in a newer version without upgrading the project this macro doesn't reflect the compiler being used - only the IDE version.

Comment: I'm in the process of compilinf libFLAC together with some other libraries. They require compilation to be done using toolset v100. There's a code `#if defined _MSC_VER
#  if _MSC_VER >= 1800
#    include <inttypes.h>`. inttypes.h cannot be found, though. Very strange

Comment: The place you linked to claims VS 2017 is MSVC++ version 15.0, but your answer claims it's MSVC++ 14.1. Which one is correct?

Comment: @thomthom : This macro exactly reflects the Toolset version used by the selected target of the build project. Or more distinct: Project->Properties->General->Platform Toolset.

Comment: @chrisw We now document this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2017, see ```_MSC_VER ```. Hope this helps

Answer (score 51):

Yep _MSC_VER is the macro that'll get you the compiler version.  The last number of releases of Visual C++ have been of the form `<compiler-major-version>.00.<build-number>`, where 00 is the minor number.  So `_MSC_VER` will evaluate to `<major-version><minor-version>`.

You can use code like this:

```
#if (_MSC_VER == 1500)
   // ... Do VC9/Visual Studio 2008 specific stuff
#elif (_MSC_VER == 1600)
   // ... Do VC10/Visual Studio 2010 specific stuff
#elif (_MSC_VER == 1700)
   // ... Do VC11/Visual Studio 2012 specific stuff
#endif
```

It appears updates between successive releases of the compiler, have not modified the `compiler-minor-version`, so the following code is not required:

```
#if (_MSC_VER >= 1500 && _MSC_VER <= 1600)
   // ... Do VC9/Visual Studio 2008 specific stuff
#endif
```

Access to more detailed versioning information (such as compiler build number) can be found using other builtin pre-processor variables [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

Comment: you just need to check == 1500 in that case

Comment: @José, true we could simplify it to just check for VC++ 9 with `_MSC_VER_ == 1500`, however if MS, did modify the `_MSC_VER` with compiler updates, service packs, etc (I don't think they ever have), then the `== 1500` check could break.  Which is why I've coded it that way.

Comment: __MSC_VER evaluate to the major and minor number components of the compiler's version. This will not change with an update, there is _MSC_FULL_VER with include the build number too, i have never need to use that.

Comment: I will up-vote the answer if you edit it to clarify this. Bests Jose.

Comment: @José: Answer updated to give a more correct and detailed answer.

Answer (score 11):

_MSC_VER should be defined to a specific version number.  You can either #ifdef on it, or you can use the actual define and do a runtime test.  (If for some reason you wanted to run different code based on what compiler it was compiled with?  Yeah, probably you were looking for the #ifdef. :))

Answer (score 7):

By using the `_MSC_VER` macro.

Answer (score 4):

As a more general answer http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/ maintains a list of macros for detecting specicic compilers, operating systems, architectures, standards and more.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little old but should get you started:

```
//******************************************************************************
// Automated platform detection
//******************************************************************************

// _WIN32 is used by
// Visual C++
#ifdef _WIN32
#define __NT__
#endif

// Define __MAC__ platform indicator
#ifdef macintosh
#define __MAC__
#endif

// Define __OSX__ platform indicator
#ifdef __APPLE__
#define __OSX__
#endif

// Define __WIN16__ platform indicator 
#ifdef _Windows_
#ifndef __NT__
#define __WIN16__
#endif
#endif

// Define Windows CE platform indicator
#ifdef WIN32_PLATFORM_HPCPRO
#define __WINCE__
#endif

#if (_WIN32_WCE == 300) // for Pocket PC
#define __POCKETPC__
#define __WINCE__
//#if (_WIN32_WCE == 211) // for Palm-size PC 2.11 (Wyvern)
//#if (_WIN32_WCE == 201) // for Palm-size PC 2.01 (Gryphon)  
//#ifdef WIN32_PLATFORM_HPC2000 // for H/PC 2000 (Galileo)
#endif
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot more than the top voted one.
Because _MSC_VER requires that you include stdio.h

Comment: `_MSC_VER` does not require you to include `stdio.h`, which can be easily tested `echo int i = _MSC_VER; > tmp.c` `cl /nologo /c tmp.c`

Comment: @J.M.I.MADISON : Not only is it not true regarding _MSC_VER which is a _predefined macro_, this answer clearly does not answer the question - it detects the platform, not the compiler version version.

Answer (score -9):

In visual studio, go to help | about and look at the version of Visual Studio that you're using to compile your app.

Comment: This can't be serious.  Especially from someone with a reputation like this.  I assume you were just making a joke?

Comment: I think he just interpreted the question in a different manner. After all, this is one of the first answers to the question.

Comment: AFAIK @Haacked is valid and correct, as the question does not include "from my code" or other statement telling that he/she is not already using a VS IDE.