# How do I check for C++11 support?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to detect at compile-time if the compiler supports certain features of C++11?  For example, something like this:

```
#ifndef VARIADIC_TEMPLATES_SUPPORTED

#error "Your compiler doesn't support variadic templates.  :("

#else

template <typename... DatatypeList>
class Tuple
{
    // ...
}

#endif
```

Comment: You could have a header called "assert_variadic_template_support.hpp" that you can include and within do something like `template <typename... Test> struct compiler_must_support_variadic_templates;`. A syntax error would quickly reveal the problem. (Just as an aside, a proper error message is much better.)

Comment: The 'right' way to solve this problem is a configure test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Quick history

When this question was asked in February 2011, support for C++11 was inconsistent. Compilers needed time to catch up to the standard, so in the meantime, they released with partial support. For example, a compiler might have implemented variadic templates, but not `auto`.

If you had code that depended on a subset of C++11 features, you didn't have a standard way of asking the compiler whether it supported them specifically.

You could [check](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros) for *overall* C++11 support with `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L`, but:

- That constant and its meaning weren't technically official until the standard was accepted later, in August 2011.
- This was too coarse. Compilers probably only set `__cplusplus` to `201103L` once they had *full* feature support—and no one had full feature support yet. So, if you used this, you would unnecessarily reject most or all of the compilers that people would want to use to compile your code.

One pragmatic solution was to use the third-party [Boost.Config](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) library, which maintained [a bunch of feature test macros](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__11_features_not_supported). `Boost.Config`'s maintainers kept track of which compilers supported which features, and updated the macros accordingly for each `Boost.Config` release.

(This stuff about Boost is based on an [early, now-deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5047980/497934) from [@James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151292/james-mcnellis).

## Today

### C++11

Today, [there's a version of every major compiler that supports the whole C++11 standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B11_features). .

If your code requires *any* of C++11, it's now reasonable to require that the compiler supports *all* of C++11. So, use `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L`. ([See @Paulo M's answer for a standards reference for this macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29407260/497934).) But beware that there are [complications with MSVC](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/)—see [@Donald Duck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40512515/497934).

### Beyond

Since C++20, in addition to the coarse-grained `__cplusplus` macro, you can also [`#include <version>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/version) to get [a bunch of feature test macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test). This is basically a standards-based alternative to `Boost.Config`.

According to [this answer from Jarryd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35399513/497934), these macros are actually available in at least some 2016-era C++14 compilers.

Comment: I really wish there were additional macros which specify the respective version number assigned to a given standard. I.e., I wish the next C++ ISO standard would specify e.g.__cplusplus1998 as 199711L, __cplusplus2011 as 201103L, __cplusplus2014 as 201402L etc. Each new standard would add its own macro to the list. I have to look the values up every time I want to use one, and it is too easy to make typos.

Answer (score 127):

There is a constant named `__cplusplus` that C++ compilers should set to the version of the C++ standard supported [see this](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#11)

```
#if __cplusplus <= 199711L
  #error This library needs at least a C++11 compliant compiler
#endif
```

It is set to 199711L in Visual Studio 2010 SP1, but I do not know if vendors will be so bold to increase it already if they just have (partial) compiler-level support versus a standard C++ library with all the C++11 changes.

So Boost's defines mentioned in another answer remain the only sane way to figure out if there is, for example, support for C++11 threads and other specific parts of the standard.

Comment: C++11 sets the value of `__cplusplus` to `201103L`. That asserts full conformance to the 2011 standard; it doesn't tell you about partial conformance or compiler extensions. If `__cplusplus` is set to `201103L`, then either the compiler fully conforms or it's lying to you. If it's not, then you can't really tell which features it supports.

Comment: g++ 4.7.x (and presumably newer) sets this when `-std=c++11` option is specified (may also with `-std=gnu++11`).  They do this, even though they are not quite feature complete (4.8 brings us a lot closer).  Note - there is a gap between what the compiler supports and what's available in the standard library. Both 4.7.x & 4.8.x are currently missing regex support - but that's a library, not a compiler feature.

Comment: I wonder why this is not the accepted answer. Also, you could use [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/how-do-i-check-for-c11-support#comment23849959_10849807) to further improve your answer, it's very good.

Comment: @KeithThompson For me, both Code::Blocks and Visual Studio set the value of `__cplusplus` to `199711L` for C++ 11.

Comment: @DonaldDuck: Strictly speaking, no, they don't. A compiler that sets `__cplusplus` to `199711L` is not a conforming C++11 compiler. They probably have options to make them behave correctly.

Comment: This answer makes no sense; why would we look for 1997, if we need to test for C++11 support.  C++ was first standardized in 1998, so every C++ compiler should be setting this to at  least 199711 if it conforms to any version of ISO C++ at all.

Comment: Regarding *"I do not know if vendors will be so bold to increase it already if they just have (partial) compiler-level support versus a standard C++ library with all the C++11 changes."*   The assumption should be that the OP wants a test of a decently high confidence for C++11. If the vendors are not bold enough to announce C++11 support via `__cplusplus`, then the confidence level is poor. Some C++11 feature the program depends on might in fact not be there.

Comment: 199711L was the best available information at the time. In Stroustrup's own words: "In C++11 the macro __cplusplus will be set to a value that differs from (is greater than) the current 199711L. " - feel free to give an up-vote to more recent answers with the actual constant used in the finalized standard, I'll do the same! | Adoption happens incrementally, so I think it was fair to mention Boost for more granular checking :)

Answer (score 42):

As stated by the **C++11** standard (§iso.16.8):

> The name **__cplusplus** is defined to the value **201103L** when
>   compiling a C++ translation unit.

With the value of that macro, you can check whether the compiler is C++11 compliant.

Now, if you are looking for a standard way to check if the compiler supports a whatsoever subset of C++11 features, I think there is no standard, portable way; you can check compilers documentation or std library header files to get more information.

Comment: For example, static_assert is supported in VS2010 and in all c++11 copilers. So, if you check for a value of  __cplusplus greater or equal than the one set in VS2010 (i.e. >= 199711L), you can be fine.

Answer (score 37):

I know that this is a very old question, but this question might be often seen, and the answers are a bit out of date.

Newer compilers with the C++14 standard have a standard way to check features, including C++11 features. A comprehensive page is at https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations

In summary, each feature has a standard macro defined that you can check with `#ifdef`. For example, to check for user defined literals, you can use

```
#ifdef __cpp_user_defined_literals
```

Comment: I didn't know that. I think that this simple feature is coming late, but still can be very useful, especially the `__has_include()` macro.

Comment: Does it exist for C++20 or C++23 features ? It is quite painful that, when using a C++20 feature, you never know if the compiler implements it. I know that there is a list on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20 but it is not obvious to find the feature from its title and I don't want to check everytime I use a feature..

Answer (score 29):

You can use this:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L || (defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1900)
    cout << "C++11 is supported";
#else
    cout << "C++11 is not supported";
#endif
```

For C++11, most compilers set the `__cplusplus` macro at `201103L`. But Visual Studio, [depending on how old it is and how it's configured](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/), sets it at `199711L`, which is the value used by other compilers for *before* C++11.

This code compares the `_cplusplus` macro with `201103L` for all compilers except Visual Studio, and if the compiler is Visual Studio, it checks if the version of Visual Studio is later than 2015, the first version of Visual Studio which completely supports C++11 (for Visual Studio 2015, the `_MSC_VER` macro has the value `1900`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630/4284627)).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. For `g++ -std=c++98` with GCC 4.8, it incorrectly prints `C++11 is supported`.

Comment: @pts Sorry, just a typo. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 25):

For check support C++14 and other. Testing on GCC 5.2.1.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
        #if __cplusplus==201402L
        std::cout << "C++14" << std::endl;
        #elif __cplusplus==201103L
        std::cout << "C++11" << std::endl;
        #else
        std::cout << "C++" << std::endl;
        #endif

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you do not want to use Boost.Config and need to test for compilers that support C++11 then checking the value of the constant `__cplusplus` will do. However, a compiler might support most of the popular features of the C++11 standard yet it does not support the entire specifications. If you want to enable support for specific Visual Studio compilers which are not yet 100% compliant to C++11 specifications then use the following code snippet which allows compiling in Visual Studio 2013:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#   if _MSC_VER < 1800 
#       error This project needs atleast Visual Studio 2013
#   endif
#elif __cplusplus <= 199711L
#   error This project can only be compiled with a compiler that supports C++11
#endif
```

A complete list of versions of the compiler for Visual Studio is provided at [How to Detect if I'm Compiling Code With Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70013/how-to-detect-if-im-compiling-code-with-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: This test will succeed in any C++ compiler that conforms to C++98 or later and that is not the Microsoft C++ compiler.

Answer (score 6):

In the traditional Linux/Unix world, autoconf is traditionally used to test for the presence of libraries and compiler features and bugs placing them into a config.h that you use in your files as needed.

Comment: Yes autoconf can be used to test for features but it you must make it generate the appropriate macro for failure or successes that can then be tested by the code above. So by itself this answer adds no information.

Comment: @LokiAstari: That's not how autoconf works. Autoconf provides macros that let you have your configure script compile a test source file and set the #define to 0 or 1 based on the success of the compilation. diverscuba23's answer provides information by pointing out the OP is reaching for a suboptimal solution to the real problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11909347/580412 https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html

Answer (score 2):

When your check is for a C++11 library availability (not a language feature), for example the `<array>` header, you can `#if __has_include(<array>)`.

Sometimes checking `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L` would tell you that you use C++11 but other settings like the standard library version setting in Xcode may still not have the new libraries available (most of them are available in different names ie `<tr1/array>`)