# Can I query the compiler about C++0x "alignas" support?

Tags: c++, c++11, alignment, conditional-compilation

I'm writing a few classes and structs that could benefit from 16-byte alignment.  Instead of using compiler-specific hacks, I'd rather use the new C++0x `alignas` functionality for future portability.  However, using it outside of appropriate `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` guards will obviously cause errors on compilers without `alignas` support.

I did a quick search for similar questions, and [the closest match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/detecting-c0x-support) had an answer recommending `Boost.Config`.  Unfortunately, `Boost.Config` doesn't seem to include any functionality for querying `alignas` support.  Are there any other `#ifdef`s or `#ifndef`s I can use to figure out whether the compiler supports it?

Thanks!

Comment: This is what Autoconf is for surely?

Comment: Is there a way to specifically check for alignas support with autoconf?  Even if there is though, I don't think autoconf is an option for me.  Even if I didn't dread the thought of learning configuration scripting, it's only applicable to the GNU toolchain anyway, right?  In the general sense, I wouldn't want to restrict my code to the GNU build system.  In my specific case, I'm writing a C++ plugin for Avisynth, which needs to be compiled by MSVC anyway (although some have had success with ICC).

Comment: BTW, I understand that I could just use __declspec(align(16)) for this particular project (now that I've specified MSVC ;)).  Similarly, I could just use __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) if I were specifically targeting GCC (which I'm not in this case).  In other words, being unable to test for alignas(16) isn't exactly a showstopper.  I guess I'm just wanting to form a habit of using the new standard functionality where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no direct feature-support macros for the various C++0x (C++11) facilities. There only two ways I can think of to determine their presence.

1. Keep a list of which compilers support them, and use `#ifdef` directives based on the compiler-supplied version macros such as `__GNUC__` and `_MSC_VER`, or
2. Use a feature-detection script such as autoconf to detect compiler support prior to building, and construct a header file with your own macros indicating support for the feature, or lack thereof.

Using Boost.Config is actually an example of both: Boost has a set of feature-detection scripts which are run during Boost development, and then the results hard-coded in the Boost.Config headers based on the compiler version macros.

Comment: Thank you.  Since there aren't any standard macros and Boost.Config devs haven't gotten around to adding a check for that particular feature, I suppose it just comes down to autotools or manually tracking compiler versions.  That's a shame, but those are the breaks. :)