# Using find_if within instance method

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have an instance method that populates a vector of strings.  I am trying to find the one vector entry that contains a specific substring (for now, that substring is fixed - simple).

I have a `.h`:

```
namespace Data
{
namespace Shared
{

    class Logger
    {
      public:
        bool FindLogDirectoryPredicate(const string &str);
        int GetLogDirectory(string logConfigFile, string& logDirectory);
...
    }
}
}
```

and `.cpp`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include "Logger.h"

bool Logger::FindLogDirectoryPredicate(const string &str) 
{
    // Return false if string found.
    return str.find("File=") > 0 ? false : true;
}

int Logger::GetLogDirectory(string logConfigFile, string& logDirectory)
{
    vector<string> fileContents;
    ...
    vector<string>::iterator result = find_if(fileContents.begin(), fileContents.end(), FindLogDirectoryPredicate);
    ...
}
```

Compiling this in Visual Studio 2010, I receive:

```
Error   7   error C3867: 'Data::Shared::Logger::FindLogDirectoryPredicate': function call missing argument list; use '&Data::Shared::Logger::FindLogDirectoryPredicate' to create a pointer to member   Logger.cpp  317 1   Portability
```

Throwing an & in front of the function ref in the find_if call then results in:

```
Error   7   error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression    Logger.cpp  317 1   Portability
```

I did try to put the predicate function outside the class, but that didn't seem to work - gave me a function not found error.  Tried qualifying the predicate with the class name... that gave me a different error in algorithm (header):

```
Error   1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\algorithm    83  1   Portability
```

The example I was following from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) seems to indicate that this is relatively simple.... so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `FindLogDirectoryPredicate` is an *instance* method: it's not enough to specify its name, you somehow have to specify *which object* that method should be called on. Now the answer to this question is obvious to us (`this`), but not to the compiler.

The classic way to do this is with

```
find_if(fileContents.begin(), 
        fileContents.end(), 
        bind1st(mem_fun(&Logger::FindLogDirectoryPredicate), this));
```

What's going on here?

[`mem_fun`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun/) "converts a member function to a function object". That is, it creates an instance of a type (what type exactly is unspecified, but we don't care) that exposes `operator()` (this is what we do care about!). This operator expects the first parameter to be a pointer to an instance of the type that defines the member function; here, that would be an instance of `Logger`.

[`bind1st`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/bind1st/) then takes this function object that takes two parameters (first is the pointer to instance, second is the original `const string &` parameter) and returns a different function object that takes just one parameter (the `const string &`). The other parameter is fixed to the value of `bind1st`'s second argument (`this`).

Alternatively, if you can make `FindLogDirectoryPredicate` `static` then there's no longer any need to specify which instance to call it on, so the problem will automatically go away.

Comment: Thank you Jon (and sehe and Andrey).  I've accepted this answer as it offered an explanation as well as a solution.  I've specified the predicate as static and the code now compiles.  Now, on to testing.  Thanks again... knew it had to be something relatively simple.

Answer (score 3):

Make the predicate `static`

```
class Logger
{
  public:
    static bool FindLogDirectoryPredicate(const string &str);
}
```

Or perhaps, use a lambda.

```
result = std::find_if(begin(), end(), [&this] (const std::string& s) 
     { return FindLogDirectoryPredicate(s); } );
```

You can also use a std::mem_fun (and related `<functional>` stuff) if you must use C++98/C++03

```
result = std::find_if(begin(), end(), 
     std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&Logger::FindLogDirectoryPredicate), this) );
```

Comment: I don't think mem_fun_ref would work.  The best you can get out of that is calling member functions with no arguments.  You'd need bind from tr1 or boost.

Comment: @NathanMonteleone of course, you'd need to bind argument, which the standard library has supported from C++98 no problem. Expanded my sample. Boost is nice too

Comment: What do you mean by "use a lambda"?  Also, not sure what you are referring to with "C++98/C++03"?  I gather they're version #'s of the language, but how does one determine what is used (and what is available to a given compiler)?

Comment: Recent compilers (gcc, clang, VC10/11) implement (a subset) of the latest C++11 spec which supports lambdas. My answer already shows what they look like. See also [C++11 support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/detecting-c11-support) and [Lambdas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: @sehe Neat, I didn't realize mem_fun could peel off arguments like that.

Comment: Have done some reading on lambdas and those are really cool!  I wound up writing one for our application as this is one of those "one-off" situations.  Thanks!  If I could set multiple answers as accepted, I would add this one as well!

Answer (score -1):

Make your predicate a static class member.

```
static bool FindLogDirectoryPredicate(const string &str);
```