# C++ best way to modify a given member of all objects in a vector of these objects

Tags: c++, vector

I have an `std::vector` of objects. For each object in the vector, I want to modify the value of an object member. The following thoughts came into my mind:

1. If I had a vector of *primitives*, I would use `std::fill` to do that. However, I cannot imagine how to apply `std::fill` to a vector of *objects*.
2. I know that I could definitely iterate over all objects using an iterator but that is much code for a tiny task.

**What is the best way to modify the value of an object member for all objects in `std::vector`?**

Comment: `std::for_each` with a a lambda perhaps?

Comment: Does std::transform work?

Comment: Why do you consider a simple for loop, which just does one thing, "much code"?  It's really not.

Comment: @RedX: yes, following minicaptain, I tried `std::for_each` with lambda.

Comment: If without c++11, you can try BOOST_FOREACH macro, that results in less code compared to a for() loop.

Comment: If you dont want to loop, just update the value in the operator overloading like *, ->, = and copy cons. This will make sure that the value is set before the object is used. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use lambda to handle this problem;
just like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int temp = 10;
    vector<int> ivec = {30, -10, -20, 50, 40 ,100, -50};
    std::for_each(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), [&](int &x) { x += temp; cout << x << endl;});
    return 0;
}
```

but only c11 support lambda，you must make sure your complier support c11！

Comment: thank You, I applied the for_each (+1). Mmhh..when I checked my compiler for C++11 support recently, as done in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/how-do-i-check-for-c11-support), it showed a 'pre-C++11' version. However, it works and looks concise to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid the for loop with iterators, you have various ways.

`std::for_each` with functor structure:

```
 struct Functor
 { 
    Functor(int new_value)
    { 
        _new_value = new_value;
    }

    void operator()(Object& object)
    {
        object.modify = _new_value;
    }

    int   _new_value;
 };

std::for_each(objects.begin(), objects.end(), Functor(1));
```

`std::for_each` with function:

```
  void function_modify(Object& object)
  {
      object.modify = 2;
  }

  std::for_each(objects.begin(), objects.end(), function_modify);
```

`std::for_each` with lambda:

```
 std::for_each(objects.begin(), objects.end(), [](Object& object) { object.modify = 3; } );
```

c++11 for loop:

```
for (auto& object: objects) { object.modify = 4; }
```

http://ideone.com/n1SNnL

Comment: Both of those options require C++11, not just the second.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You're right, lambda are C++11 only. I add the non C++11 one (functor) ASAP

Answer (score 2):

I may have not well understand your needs, but if you want to affect a value for each same field of your `vector` elements, here are some methods :

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    char b;
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<MyStruct> myVector;

    //... Fill the vector

    // First way
    for(std::vector<MyStruct>::iterator vIt = myVector.begin() ; vIt != myVector.end() ; ++vIt)
        vIt->a = 42;

    // C++11
    for(auto vIt = myVector.begin() ; vIt != myVector.end() ; ++vIt)
        vIt->a = 42;

    // Also C++11
    for(MyStruct& vElement : myVector)
        vElement.a = 42;

    // Even more C++11
    for(auto& vElement : myVector)
        vElement.a = 42;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are even more if you count in the `std::algorithm` solutions like `transform` and `for_each` with lambda.

Comment: Thanks Oragon Efreet (+1), the third example looks pretty concise to me. If I had C++11 available in my project, I would have used it!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly all i can think of is to iterate over the objects. If you don't want to use an iterator you could give [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) a go.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
std::vector<Object> v( 10, Object() );

for ( Object &obj : v ) obj.member = value;
```

or

```
std::vector<Object> v( 10, Object() );

std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), []( Object &obj ) { obj.member = value; } );
```

or

```
Object obj;
obj.member = value;

std::vector<Object> v( 10, obj );
```

or

```
std::vector<Object> v;

Object obj;
obj.member = value;

v.assign( 10, obj );
```

Answer (score 0):

If looping is not preferable, you can do this

```
class myClass
{
    int a; // Variable to be modified

    public:

    myClass (const myClass&t)
    {
       a = 5;// assumed value to be set
    }

    myClass& operator=()
    {
        a = 5;// assumed value to be set
        return *this;
    }

    myClass& operator*()
    {
       a= 5; // assumed value to be set
       return *this;
    }
};
```

This will make sure that the value is set before the object is used, and thereby partly solve your problem.