# Take variable number of arguments and put them in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, overloading

I'm making a class - let's call it `Container` - that is basically just containing a `std::vector` and some special logic that decides how are the vector values picked. I want to add a method for adding multiple values to my class with one call. This is my method that adds one item:

```
void LoopGenerator::add(RandomStripe &stripe)
{
    stripes.push_back(new SingleStripe(stripe));
}
```

I'd like a similar method that would be called like this:

```
LoopGenerator gen = LoopGenerator();
gen.add(RandomStripe(), RandomStripe(), RandomStripe() ... and as much as you want ... );
```

and would add all parameters to the inner `std::vector`.

Is this possible to do just with standard libraries, or best without them?

Comment: A traditional va_args would require some way to know how many parameters were passed. Alternatively, you can use variadic templates, if available.

Comment: @Tomáš Zato What are RandomStripe and SingleStripe? Are they different types?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, they are different. Actually, `SingleStripe` just exists so `RandomStripe` can be with array along with other stripe generating classes... `SingleStripe` derives from same class as `LoopGenerator`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use std::initializer_list. For example

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>    


//...

void LoopGenerator::add( std::initializer_list<RandomStripe> stripe )
{
    std::transform( stripe.begin(), stripe.end(), 
                   std::back_inserter( stripes ),
                   []( const RandomStripe &s ) { return new SingleStripe( s ); } );
}
```

And call it like

```
gen.add( { RandomStripe(), RandomStripe(), RandomStripe(), /*...*/ } );
```

Comment: I was rewriting the code so it took me a while to get to using your answer. I get following error: `cannot open source file "initializer_list"` Should I reconfigure my project?

Comment: @Tomáš Zato What compiler are you using? Does it support C++ 2011?

Comment: [Quick search](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10849807/607407) suggests that it doesn't. But I'm working in MS Visual Studio. It's quite complex and confusing. Maybe it could be enabled somewhere.

Comment: @Tomáš Zato What is the version of MS VS?

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++11 you could utilize variadic templates to accomplish this.

In prior versions I would suggest just doing method chaining:

```
LoopGenerator& LoopGenerator::add(RandomStripe &stripe)
{
    stripes.push_back(new SingleStripe(stripe));
    return *this;
}
```

And call it `gen.add(RandomStripe()).add(RandomStripe()).add(RandomStripe());`

Comment: as the number of elements to be added to stack increases should user change the code to add one more call of function add() ?