# Determine whether thread_local keyword is supported on compile time

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to use `thread_local` keyword in my project.  However, not all the compiler that supports `-std=c++11` supports `thread_local`.  Can I know whether there's a way to determine whether `thread_local` is supported on compile time?  I tried googling it but didn't find the answer.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/how-do-i-check-for-c11-support) wont tell you if `thread_local` is supported but you can tell if C++11 is being used.

Comment: The usual way is to use thread_local, if it does not compile then grab whatever macros identify given compiler and use ifdef-s to replace it with something that works.

Comment: The usual technique (with linux installation packages) is to run a configure script that tries to compile a small code snippet and checks the compiler's exit status. A configuration header file is then generated containing a number of defines that tell you what can be used in your code, and what cannot be used.

Comment: @luskan That's a bit shortcut and clumsy.

Comment: I don't think it's an optional part of the standard, so you are sort of asking for a standardized way to find out if the compiler adheres to the standard or not.  I think you are down to a bunch of #ifdefs, or make configure.

Comment: @MartinBonner [Agreed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Answer (score 2):

> However, not all the compiler that supports `-std=c++11` supports `thread_local`.

According to [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) they need to, to be c++11 standard compliant.

So your question basically boils down to determine if parts of your code are compiled with the `-std=c++11` option or not, which is already well [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/how-do-i-check-for-c11-support).

---

If you see differences with particular OS environments/C++ Compiler implementations, I'd recommend to run a pre-compilation script, that probes for particular compiler capabilities, and generate a `config.h` header for you.

Including this header can be used to determine, if particular features are available and you can place appropriate

```
 #if defined(FEATURE)
     // feature specific code
 #else
     // plain code
 #endif
```

in your header and source files.

---

To support the latter option I have introduced, there are the [GNU automake tools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/index.html#Top), which support to generate such probing script. It's available to support a broad variety of target platforms.

Comment: your answer suggests you have never compiled on a mac with clang after the clowns at Apple have done their best to destroy it. :/

Comment: @RichardHodges No I didn't actually. But it's actually required to be implemented by c++11 compliant compilers. So those you mention have bugs? That would require additional `#ifdef` to sort out unless that's gonna be fixed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, there is at least one much used thing outside which is supposed to be c++11 conformant, yet misses all thread-special parts of C++11. Namely, mingw and the version of gcc they provide.

Comment: @SergeyA Fair point. But still necessary to sort these out specifcally from system configurations, no?

Comment: @RichardHodges Rant on their posts please, not on mine.

Comment: clang-700.1.81 on Apple for example, does support -std=c++11 but not support thread_local.

Comment: #if defined(FEATURE) does not work actually, it only works for macro.  See  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html