# Getting the C++ standard version Visual Studio uses

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 for my programming tasks, and I was wondering what version of the C++ standard the compiler used.

Googling didn't result in anything.

I tested those conditions, but they don't work properly:

```
if (__cplusplus == 201103L) std::cout << "C++11\n";
else if (__cplusplus == 201402L) std::cout << "C+14\n";
else if (__cplusplus == 19971L) std::cout << "C++98\n";
else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";
```

The output is `pre-standard`. However, I don't think that my C++ standard is `pre-standard` because I can use `auto` when specifying a type, which can only be used in C++11.

So, is there any easy way to get the C++ standard in Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't know an easy way to get a value programmatically, especially because it may support some but not all features of a particular standard, but you can see the features it supports from each standard iteration here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: Have you tried just printing out the value of the macro `__cplusplus`?

Comment: There are various macros to test implemented features here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros. I don't know if VS implements those macros though.

Comment: I think VS does, but because it never fully conforms a C++ standard, it may have some in-between value :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27459246/560648

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I didn't, but I will test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `else if (__cplusplus == 19971L) std::cout << "C++98\n";`.
It should be `else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) std::cout << "C++98\n";`.

This is still the version in VS2015, probably because it still doesn't support the standard to the full extent.