# remove thread::hardware_concurrency by preprocessor if not declared

Tags: c++, multithreading, header, c-preprocessor

I have C++ code that uses

```
int nthreads = thread::hardware_concurrency();
```

When I try to build my application on some computers, I get the error message

```
error: 'thread' has not been declared
```

I do not ask how to solve the error. I'm more interested in if there is a special "guard" that I can use to simply remove the lines of code by the preprocessor like for example in OpenMP I can use:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
...
#endif
```

Comment: Are you asking the right question?  Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Solving the error would be better than trying to detect when you need to avoid it.

Comment: "*error: 'thread' has not been declared*" - did you remember to use `#include <thread>`? And probably also `using namespace std;` or better `using std::thread;` since you are not fully qualifying `hardware_concurrency()` as `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`, only as `thread::hardware_concurrency()`

Answer (score 4):

`std::thread::hardware_concurrency` is provided by C++11. If compilers on those "some computers" support it you may have to toggle C++11 support (e.g. with mingw/gcc `-std=c++11`).

To disable `hardware_concurrency` usage when unavailable, the best solution might be to detect C++11 support.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40512515/6261331) may work out for you, even if you use Visual Studio:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L || (defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1900)
    int nthreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
#else
    int nthreads = 4; // whatever fallback value
#endif
```

Do note that it detects the VS 2015 compiler version as it was the first one to advertize full C++11 support. You can tweak the `_MSC_VER` check to an older version if `hardware_concurrency` happens to be available on older VS compilers.