# Using TR1 libraries in GCC and MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, tr1

I would like to use the TR1 libraries that ship with modern versions of GCC and MSVC, but there are subtle differences: in GCC, I have to say

```
#include <tr1/memory>
std::tr1::shared_ptr<int> X;
```

while in MSVC I have to say

```
#include <memory>
std::shared_ptr<int> X;
```

I have two questions: 1) Does MSVC automatically operate in C++0x-mode (equivalent to GCC's std=c++0x), or does it also work in C++98/03 mode by default? 2) How can I unify the includes and namespaces? I was thinking about a preprocessor macro of the sort "INCLUDE_TR1(memory)" or something like that.

To clarify, I want to use the traditional, standard C++98/03; *not* C++0x (otherwise there'd be no problem).

I'd be most grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: std::tr1::shared_ptr works on my MSVC10.

Comment: MF: Thank you. TG: The most general answer you can give would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after having several inconsistent and unsurmountable problems with Boost.TR1, especially when trying to use GCC's native TR1 libraries, I decided to ditch Boost entirely and use a small #define workaround. Here is my "tr1.h":

```
#ifndef _TR1_INCLUDE_H
#define _TR1_INCLUDE_H

/** Usage: #include TR1INCLUDE(unordered_map)
 **
 ** Configuration: Define HAVE_TR1_SUBDIR if you need #include <tr1/unordered_map>; otherwise we take #include <unordered_map>.
 **
 **/

#define QUOTE(arg) <arg>

#ifdef HAVE_TR1_SUBDIR
#  define TR1IFY(arg) tr1/arg
#else
#  define TR1IFY(arg) arg
#endif

#define TR1INCLUDE(arg) QUOTE(TR1IFY(arg))

#endif
```

Now I can just write my programs like this:

```
#include "tr1.h"
#include TR1INCLUDE(unordered_map)
```

Answer (score 4):

1. VC++ 2010 *only* operates in C++0x mode; previous versions had no C++0x support. That said, much of the standard library in VC++ 2010 is is still based on TR1 (e.g. `std::result_of<>` uses the TR1 result_of protocol instead of being `decltype`-based); in fact, much of the standard library in VC++ 2010 is not actually defined in namespace `std`, but rather in namespace `std::tr1` and pulled into namespace `std` with a using directive.
2. Use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[TR1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tr1/index.html) -- it will `#include` the appropriate headers according to your platform, or if your platform doesn't have TR1 support, `#include` the corresponding Boost implementations and pull them into namespace `std::tr1` with using declarations.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm told (buy the Windows people) that "std::tr1::shared_ptr" doesn't work; they _have_ to use std::shared_ptr. Am I maybe misremembering that? If the namespace could always be taken as "std::tr1", then that'd already be half the weight off the problem.

Comment: @Kerrek SB : I'm not sure what you're saying; in VC++ 2010, there *is no* definition of `std::shared_ptr<>`, only a definition of `std::tr1::shared_ptr<>` that is pulled into namespace `std` with a using directive. So, of course using `std::tr1::shared_ptr<>` is safe.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that, since I don't have the compiler. I thought somebody told me that in order to make my GCC code work they had to replace <tr1/memory> by <memory> and std::tr1::shared_ptr by std::shared_ptr, but they may just not have tested std::tr1::shared_ptr. Thanks a lot for clarifying this!

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 with the TR1 patch requires the `tr1` in the namespace.  But, IIRC, it's GCC that requires `tr1` in the header path, and Visual Studio 2008 with the Tr1 patch that just adds the new stuff to the old header.

Comment: We're using CMake. I'm now playing with Boost.TR1. I find Boost with CMake, and I add "-D BOOST_HAS_GCC_TR1" to the GCC options (and no changes to the MSVC options), and I turn all headers into C++0x style (<unordered_map> etc.). Fingers crossed.

Comment: @Kerrek SB : Correct regarding `#include`s; with GCC you need `<tr1/memory>` whereas with VC++ 2008 SP1 or VC++ 2010 you need `<memory>`. But, that's half the purpose of Boost.TR1 -- it `#include`s the correct headers *for you* depending on platform.

Answer (score 4):

VC++ 2010 **always** operates in C++0x mode, but the classes exist in both the `std` *and* `std::tr1` namespaces.  You’ll have to detect the compiler with an `#if _MSC_VER` to choose which headers to include (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630/1136311)).

The [Boost.TR1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_tr1.html) library can automatically include your compiler’s headers and fill in any missing functionality using Boost.  It might help.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, and the tip about Boost.TR1! Now whose answer shall I accept?

Answer (score 1):

The different versions of MSVC have the features they have. There is no way of turning them on or off.

Some of them might also have both tr1 and std versions of some features. With slightly different semantics!