# Python package install error

Tags: python, visual-studio, installation, pyml

Not exactly programming related, but about an error I am facing while trying to install a python package using python setup.py install.

I have downloaded the tar file for PyML package. Then after extracting I have done  below steps:

On DOS prompt set the  variable as below:

```
SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS110COMNTOOLS%
```

Go to the directory having setup.py in the extracted PyML folder and run:

```
python setup.py build

python setup.py install
```

But on both steps I get errors as below, related to ext/hash_map no such file found.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(336) : wa
>       rning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. S
>       pecify /EHsc
>
> e:\ajit\pyml-0.7.13.tar\dist\pyml-0.7.13\pyml\containers\ext\SparseDataSet.h(14)
>        : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ext/hash_map': No such file or
>       directory
>
> error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\cl.e
>       xe"' failed with exit status 2

What am I missing? How to resolve this error and install PyML.

Python version : 2.7.5 MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 on Windows 8 machine.

PyML version:0.7.13

Comment: No help but I have the same problem. Did you resolve it? It looks like the over-riding error is that PyML is not supported for Windows but I'd love to find out how to get it working.

Comment: @Jamie Bull - Haven't been able to resolve that error. Tried many things.

Comment: Any solutions yet? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

First, it is [recommended to use](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-April/573606.html) the same compiler as was used to build Python binaries, which is VS8:

> Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.1 are all built with that release (i.e. 2008).
>   **Because of another long tradition, Python extension modules must be
>   built with the same compiler version (more specifically, CRT version)
>   as Python itself.** So to build extension modules for any of these
>   releases, you need to have a copy of VS 2008 or VS 2008 Express.

So probably your next question fill be ["How to Enforce C++ compiler to use specific CRT version?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730134/how-to-enforce-c-compiler-to-use-specific-crt-version)

Second, this is not a solution in your case since there is different sintax in including [tr1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_Report_1) libraries in gcc and msvs, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5956576/1265154) for example. Instead of `# include <ext/hash_map>` for MSVS it must be `# include <hash_map>`. If you insist on using MSVS, you'll probably end up modifying PyML code.

Probably, you can switch to MinGW usage, here is a [step-by-step how-to](http://www.secker.nl/2012/03/08/setup-python-2-7-2-and-mingw-on-windows-xp/), althrough I didn't check whether PyML can be built this way. Won't be able to do it earlier that Nov, 14.

Comment: So If I install a Visual Studio 8 (If i manage to find installer), and retry, it might work you say.

Comment: @goldenmean didn't try, but *probably* yes, if you'll correct <ext/hash_map> to <hash_map>. I will have a test win8 machine tomorrow and gonna try MinGW.