# Distinguish between VC++ 2010 and later compiler versions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros

```
#ifdef ???
    // code for VC++ 2010 compiler
#else
    // code for later compiler versions
#endif
```

What macro can I use instead of `???`? I don't care about older compiler versions.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't get the question

Comment: [google is your friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx). Specifically, look at the `_MSC_VER`-type macros. Note that they use _compiler_ version, not the IDE version.

Comment: @billz: For example, code line `TestClass(const TestClass&) = delete;` is not compiled in VC++ 2010, but I want to have it here for VC++ 2012 and VC++ 2013 compilers. So, I need some precompiler macro to exclude this line, when VC++ 2010 is used.

Comment: I use http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/ for the list of predefined macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#if (_MSC_VER == 1600)
   //Visual C++ 2010 compiler code here...
```

Should do what you want. From here: [How to Detect if I'm Compiling Code With Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70013/how-to-detect-if-im-compiling-code-with-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 3):

For VS2010 or later:

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1600
```

Since the C/C++ compiler included with VS2010 is version 16.00.x (as displayed at the command line by `cl.exe`).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

For some measure of completeness:

```
Visual Studio   _MSC_VER
   version        value
=============  ===========
      6             1200

   2002             1300
   2003             1310
   2005             1400

   2008             1500
   2010             1600
   2012             1700

   2013             1800
```

Comment: I would probably have a nested check also, so that you cover the three options from the "question"... earlier than v16 (display a warning), v16, and later than v16.