# Is there a way to fix format specifiers warnings for stdint types?

Tags: c, printf, typedef, stdint

The problem is that on one platform (windows, mvsc2015) `uint64_t` is defined as `unsigned long long` and on another (ubuntu, clang) it's `unsigned long` and there is the code which looks like
`sprintf(buffer, "%#llx", u64key);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to use C99's format macros, in particular `PRIu64` for an `uint64_t`:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
…
sprintf(buffer, "%#" PRIu64 "\n", u64key);
```

Answer (score 4):

Pascal's solution is the most direct and most idiomatic for this particular type, but for the record, an alternative for printing arbitrary integer types whose definitions you don't know is simply casting to `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` then using the `j` modifier (e.g. `%jd` or `%ju`). This might not work on most/all versions of MSVC's standard library implementation, however, because they're way behind on standards conformance.

Comment: Can you please give an example, since my MSVC (which was the question) 2009 has neither `inttypes.h` or `PRIu64` in any other header.

Comment: @melpomene the lack of an example.

Comment: @WeatherVane Seriously? If someone told you to "multiply x by 3, then add 1", would you also ask for an example because you're absolutely unable to write code unless you can copy/paste `x*3 + 1` from SO?

Comment: @melpomene if I try "casting to intmax_t" as in say `uint64_t u64key = (intmax_t)1;` I  get a compiler error. That's why I would like an example, not waffle or ridicule.

Comment: @WeatherVane "a compiler error" is waffle. What's the error message?

Comment: @WeatherVane If your compiler does not have `inttypes.h` you could include `stdint.h` that maybe it will have. However the OP does not specify an MSVC version so, since it's 2015, we have to assume one that implements most of C99. Note that the question assumes that `uint64_t` is available **from somewhere** even on MSVC.

Comment: @WeatherVane ... so you don't have a `uint64_t` in the first place. Why are you worrying about printing one, then? http://i.imgur.com/x6AnRkL.png?fb

Comment: and since the question was "The problem is that on one platform (windows, mvsc)" and the answer says "This might not work on most/all versions of MSVC" I don't find it useful.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I do have `uint64_t` but I don't have `intmax_t` as I said.

Comment: IIRC, `intmax_t` has been added with C99, which also requires `inttypes.h`. So, if a compiler does not support C99, how to assume it provides `intmax_t` and the corresponding format specifier? Note that `intmax_t` itself is defined in `stdint.h` as much as `int32_t` & friends.

Comment: MSVC 2010 is the first release to have `<stdint.h>`/`<cstdint>`, and MSVC 2013 is the first release to have `<inttypes.h>`/`<cinttypes>`. You can test for each of them [using the `_MSC_VER` macro](http://stackoverflow.com/a/70630/539810), and if one is not found, you can try using the headers provided by the [msinttypes project on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/). Note that you'd need to create the C++ versions yourself if desired.

Comment: Note that the matter of whether MSVCRT's implementation of `printf` is conforming (in particular, whether it supports the C99 formats) is separate from whether those headers exist. It would be easy to provide the headers without providing a working library implementation.

Comment: @R.. That's very true, but I don't think anybody is using any Visual C++ version before Visual C++.NET 2003. I'm not sure if Visual C++ 6.0 knew about `%Iu` (useful for `PRIuPTR`) or `%I64u` (`PRIu64`), but it's reasonable to assume that its usage has completely disappeared. Then again, there are still people learning C in 2015 using the antiquated Turbo C++ compiler, so perhaps I'm wrong... :-(

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: Support for the nonstandard `%Iu` stuff is not relevant to this answer and comments, and not helpful. Rather it's about `%ju` which MSVCRT has not supported until very recently, if at all.

Comment: @R.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6%28v=vs.140%29.aspx : "The `hh`, `j`, `z`, and `t` length prefixes are not supported." -1 for MS here... However, that just proves that relying on `j*` instead of `PRI*MAX` is a bad idea and makes the conversion to `[u]intmax_t` nearly pointless in this case since you still need to use a `PRI*` macro.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: From my perspective it makes trying to support MSVC pointless. There are alternatives for Windows development in C; use them. Or if you really need MSVC, replace printf with a working implementation.

Comment: @R.. I agree 100%. Then again, coding in C with a compiler meant for C++ in general is arguably a bad idea.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: It is supported but not documented (yet?).

Answer (score -1):

You could use preprocessor directives to detect how a datatype is defined and compile another sprintf() with a different string.

Comment: "use preprocessor directives to detect how a datatype is defined" - ... how?