# Compiler error in inactive #ifdef block

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors, preprocessor-directive, release-mode

I am working on a c++ program that was compiled with visual studio 2013 but needs to be compiled with visual studio 2008 as well, both in release mode. I am using `#ifdef` blocks to add alternatives to functions/features that were not supported back then. The following code block is just an example:

```
struct someStruct
{
#ifdef _VS2008   // defined in preprocessor definition
    someStruct()
    {
        number = -1;
    }
    int number;
#else
    int number = -1;
#endif
    char* Text;
};
```

and I am getting the following compiler error on the line `int number = -1`.

> error C2864: 'someStruct::number' : only static const integral data
>   members can be initialized within a class

Since the code blocks under `#else` (in this case `int number = -1`) appear to be and should be inactive, why is the compiler generating errors about them?

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Because `_VS2008`, contrary to your expectations, is not defined. Incidentally, if you have to support a pre-C++11 compiler it doesn't make much sense to write double implementations of every C++11 shortcut you take - you are just making the code harder to read and risk to have the two implementations going out of sync.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Sorry I didn't clarify this, but `_VS2008` I actually defined it in the preprocessor definition. I was asked to use the ifdefs and I believe it's because this application is rarely used and it's only updated once every few years. I guess I just had to quickly get this over with. Thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found. The code blocks are in a DLL project and the main project includes some of the exported headers from it. I didn't know I had to define `_VS2008` in the main project as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `_MSC_VER` macro to detect Visual Studio version:

```
#if (_MSC_VER == 1500)
```

1500 here means VS2008. The list of versions is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630/105466).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I actually found that post too but I'm still getting errors. I'll update my question with the error I'm getting.