# How to detect if I'm compiling with the Visual Studio compiler (C1)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

There's already (more than one) QA on how to ["detect if I'm compiling with Visual Studio XXXX"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70013/4224575). However the proposed use of the `_MSC_VER_` macro does not fit my needs since I'm **using the Clang compiler** i.e. the clang front end (instead of C1) with the Visual Studio code generator (backend - C2).

Again, I'm **in** VS but use another compiler. In this scenario, how would I go about conditionally compiling my code? Is there an alternative `_CHECK_C1` macro that would allow me to do:

```
#if _CHECK_C1
// code for visual studio compiler
#else
// code for clang and gcc
#endif
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/04/clang-with-microsoft-codegen-in-vs-2015-update-1/

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: I agree, the downvotes are not deserved.  This kind of thing might happen when a question is easy to misunderstand after just cursory look, it is downvoted once, then other voters become predjudiced by the negative score and follow suit.