# error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'UINT (__thiscall CImportProjectDlg::* )(CPoint)' to 'LRESULT (__thiscall CWnd::* )(CPoint)'

Tags: visual-c++, upgrade

I am converting a VC++6.0 project to Visual Studio 2008 (enroute to 2014).  I am encountering the above error.

Here is my code snippet:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CImportProjectDlg, CDialog)
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CImportProjectDlg)
ON_WM_SIZE()
ON_WM_GETMINMAXINFO()
ON_WM_SIZING()
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_NCHITTEST()
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MERGE_IN, OnAdd)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MERGE_OUT, OnRemove)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_IMPORTPROJECT_CLEARALL, OnClearAll)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_IMPORTPROJECT_APPLY, OnApply)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDCANCEL,OnCancel)
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

And the error is indicated on the ON_WM_NCHITTEST() line.

Very puzzling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct signature for `OnNcHitTest` handler is `afx_msg LRESULT OnNcHitTest(CPoint);`. You have it return `UINT` instead of `LRESULT`.

Comment: It is unclear to me how and where to change the UINT into LRESULT.

Comment: `CImportProjectDlg` has a method named `OnNcHitTest`. This method is currently defined to return `UINT`. Change it to return `LRESULT`.

Comment: I feel a little out of my depth....   do I change the declaration:  UINT CImportProjectDlg::OnNcHitTest(CPoint point) to LRESULT.   or do I change the return code to LRESULT?

Comment: You change the return type from `UINT` to `LRESULT`, so the declaration becomes `LRESULT CImportProjectDlg::OnNcHitTest(CPoint point)`

Comment: The function is likely declared in an .h file, and defined in a .cpp file. You've updated it in one place but not the other. Update both.

Comment: Works on Windows 10/VS2017

Answer (score 1):

If you need to let the source code compiled both on VC6 and vs2008 (unfortunately), you may use `_MSC_VER` to handle it.

Full list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630/4123703)

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1500 // For vs2008+
LRESULT
#else
UINT
#endif

CImportProjectDlg::OnNcHitTest(CPoint point)
```