# How to learn a version of MSVC compiler of the MS Visual Studio 2022 installed from IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 installed and when I open from IDE the menu item *Help->About Microsoft Visual Studio* it shows Version 17.7.7 (explicitly saying "Current" for my product) and all the related components have versions 17.*

At the same time [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) suggests x64 msvc v19.37 as the latest version of the compiler and the code blow

```cpp
#include <print>

int main() {
    std::print("{}", _MSC_VER);
}
```

being run on my version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 gives the same

> 1937

Why these versions differ and is there a way to see the *msvc compiler* version installed from IDE or command line?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR: `1937` *is* the correct `_MSC_VER` for VS2022 (aka VS 17.7)

---

Since the release of Visual Studio 2017, the value of the `_MSC_VER` is entirely unrelated to the ostensible version number (or marketing version number, or release year, *or anything*, really) of Visual Studio:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-c-compiler-version/

> Starting with <del>VS “15”</del> **Visual Studio 2017** Preview 5 , the Visual C++ Team is monotonically updating the value of the built-in preprocessor macro `_MSC_VER` at every Visual C++ toolset update.
>
> [...]
>
> Each major release of the Visual C++ compiler increments the *hundredths*-part of `_MSC_VER`.
>
> Each update within a major release increments the *units*-part by 1.
>
> For example, in <del>VS “15”</del> [Visual Studio 2017] Preview 5, the macro `_MSC_VER` evaluates to `1910`. The next update [to Visual Studio 2017] will have `_MSC_VER` set to `1911`.

---

Microsoft has published a table mapping `_MSC_VER` values to Visual Studio releases [on their *Predefined Macros* page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170).

...which I've repeated here for posterity:

| Visual Studio version | `_MSC_VER` |
| --- | --- |
| Visual Studio 6.0 | 1200 |
| Visual Studio .NET 2002 (7.0) | 1300 |
| Visual Studio .NET 2003 (7.1) | 1310 |
| Visual Studio 2005 (8.0) | 1400 |
| Visual Studio 2008 (9.0) | 1500 |
| Visual Studio 2010 (10.0) | 1600 |
| Visual Studio 2012 (11.0) | 1700 |
| Visual Studio 2013 (12.0) | 1800 |
| Visual Studio 2015 (14.0) | 1900 |
| Visual Studio 2017 RTW (15.0) | 1910 |
| Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3 | 1911 |
| Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 | 1912 |
| Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6 | 1913 |
| Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7 | 1914 |
| Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 | 1915 |
| Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9 | 1916 |
| Visual Studio 2019 RTW (16.0) | 1920 |
| Visual Studio 2019 version 16.1 | 1921 |
| Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2 | 1922 |
| Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3 | 1923 |
| Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4 | 1924 |
| Visual Studio 2019 version 16.5 | 1925 |
| Visual Studio 2019 version 16.6 | 1926 |
| Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7 | 1927 |
| Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8, 16.9 | 1928 |
| Visual Studio 2019 version 16.10, 16.11 | 1929 |
| Visual Studio 2022 RTW (17.0) | 1930 |
| Visual Studio 2022 version 17.1 | 1931 |
| Visual Studio 2022 version 17.2 | 1932 |
| Visual Studio 2022 version 17.3 | 1933 |
| Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4 | 1934 |
| Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5 | 1935 |
| Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6 | 1936 |

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly the point of my question. As any documentation it is rarely catches up the current version of software. Here we can see that 17.7.7 is not covered in the table, so it would be nice to have a way to see the version "faster" to make sure it corresponds to one I am working with on godbolt.org. Of course, I can check the macro every time (and I will), but if there is a more simple way to see version of the compiler (sorry, this wasn't exactly specified in my question, but you've guessed this perfectly), it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Macro `_MSC_VER` translates to the version number of the compiler rather than the version of the IDE. This is explained [here in learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170).

One way to find the current version of Visual Studio is to execute `vswhere.exe` and evaluate its output.
This tool is located in the home directory of the Visual Studio installer `vs_installer` (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer"` on my system).

The respective output line is something like:

```
installationVersion: 17.8.34309.116
```

From the Developer Command Prompt of Visual Studio, I get the compiler version:

```
....\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community>cl /?
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33130 for x86
```

As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630/1911064) related post, you could resort to macro _MSC_FULL_VER

This results in `193833130` on my system, closely resembling the output of `cl /?`.

Comment: _"installationVersion: 17.8.34309.116"_ <-- That's the IDE version, not the `cl /?` version

Comment: Thank you, but I incorrectly asked my question. I meant that I need the compiler version (I've just updated the question). Is there a way to see the msvc compiler version somewhere from IDE (preferable) or command line?